# Chaging LOCAL_SDK_VERSION to current. is there any issues?

Tags: android, performance

I added new function in 
/frameworks/base/drm/java/android/drm/DrmManagerClient.java in Kitkat.
API level of KitKat(4.4 - 4.4.2) is 19,

But I was not able to access new function added in DrmManagerClient.java.
so I changed from 
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := 19 in Android.mk
to 
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current

Now I am able to access my new function.
As of now, I didn't face any error for changing it.

does it cause any issues which are not known to me 
or anybody faced for changing like above?

Comment: What is the sdk version you are using? I mean "current" reference to which sdk-version?

Answer (score 1):

if you set LOCAL_SDK_VERSION,maybe you can not access inner api and resources

Comment: This is not the right answer for the question, which is not very clear TBH, but it helped in my case when removing  LOCAL_SDK_VERSION allowed my test app to be compiled with @hide API usages. Thanks!